# Google Map API - Data from database

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have loaded the latitude and longitude from database using php and converted to json variable using json encode method. Now when i try to add one more value to the json variable the map goes blank.

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM enrollments";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      if($row["enrollmenttype"] == "pharmacy")
        {
          $pharmacyLatLng[$i] = "{lat: ".$row["lattitude"].", lng: ".$row["longitude"].", title: ".$row["title"]."},";

          $pharmacyCounter = ++$i;

        }
<script>
function LoadpharmacyMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(13.0102, 80.2157),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);




        //Create and open InfoWindow.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < pharmacymarkers.length; i++) {
            var data = pharmacymarkers[i];

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png'
            });

            //Attach click event to the marker.
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) {

                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is `$pharmacyLatLng` is it the variable you've generated using `json_encode(...)` ? If so, it isn't an array, it is a string, you cannot add more stuff to it using `$pharmacyLatLng[$i]`. Why don't you just convert the array to JSON after you've added all the elements to it ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed it to json_encode() and now i am able to load the map data dynamically.